# Можно ли заполнить googleform requst'ом(без селениума)?

Tags: python, node.js, request

Ищу решение, которое может заполнить данные в гугл формах requst ом, например есть такая форма: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSey4PxT0hxeWmVE17ZE4-iJkI-A5g18iFpkzUGwCBFwoTzOFQ/viewform
мне нужно заполнить форму нужными мне данными. Селениум не подойдет, нужен именно request. Язык python/node js [image: пример] https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CuDL.png

Comment: А что не так с селениум?

Comment: селениум долгий

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964429/google-forms-response-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример:

```
import requests
url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/152CTd4VY9pRvLfeACOf6SmmtFAp1CL750Sx72Rh6HJ8/formResponse'
form_data = {'entry.2020959411':'18+ sollte absolute Pflicht sein',
            'entry.2020959411':'Alter sollte garkeine Rolle spielen',
            'entry.2020959411':'17+ wäre für mich vertretbar',
            'entry.2020959411':'16+ wäre für mich vertretbar',
            'entry.2020959411':'15+ wäre für mich vertretbar',
            'entry.2020959411':'Ausnahmen von der Regel - Dafür?',
            'entry.2020959411':'Ausnahmen von der Regel - Dagegen?',
            'entry.2020959411':'__other_option__',
            'entry.2020959411.other_option_response':'test',
            'draftResponse':[],
            'pageHistory':0}
user_agent = {'Referer':'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/152CTd4VY9pRvLfeACOf6SmmtFAp1CL750Sx72Rh6HJ8/viewform','User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.52 Safari/537.36"}
r = requests.post(url, data=form_data, headers=user_agent)
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17964429/google-forms-response-with-python)

Comment: спасибо, а как достать эти цифры 2020959411 и что они означают?

Comment: @Hush Да ничего, вы туда свое подставте. ;)